# Magento 1: Redirect cache product image to default product image

Tags: magento-1.9

How to redirect cache product image to default product image ?
Is it possible via .htaccess file

```
Redirect  [BASE_URL]/media/catalog/product/m/o/art.jpg  [BASE_URL]/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab78452d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/o/art.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^/media/catalog/product/m/o/art.jpg" [BASE_URL]/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab78452d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/o/art.jpg [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Working fine....and what if that file does not exist ? can i overwrite 404 rule ?

Comment: if file not exist than its return 404